# Jquery Accordion Menu - Close then Open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple accordion menu using jQuery. When I click a link inside of one, I want that one to close, and then the other to open, any ideas on how to make this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple tutorial on how to do it. http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-menu/index_collapsed.html#